# Quelle est la plus belle forme de politesse pour effectuer une demande à un supérieur

Tags: formulation, politesse, supérieur

Quelle est la plus belle forme de politesse dans le contexte suivant :

> Lorsque l'on doit demander quelque chose à un supérieur que l'on connait. (Tutoiement autorisé)

1- Est-ce que c'est plus poli avec un "Est-ce que" au début ?

- Peux-tu m'envoyer ce document stp.
- Est-ce que tu peux m'envoyer ce document stp.

2- Quel temps de verbe est le plus poli ?

- Peux-tu m'envoyer ce document stp.
- Pourrais-tu m'envoyer ce document stp

3- Quel verbe ou formulation est le plus poli ?

- (Pouvoir) Est-ce que tu pourrais m'envoyer ce document stp.
- (Être) Serait-ce possible de m'envoyer ce document stp.
- (Autre ?)

Comment: Est-ce que tu pourrais m'envoyer....d'habitude, le conditionnel est plus poli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans le cadre que tu nous as donné, voici comment je procèderais :

1. Il est préférable, mais pas nécessaire, d'utiliser l'inversion verbe-sujet plutôt que "Est-ce que" dans le cadre d'une communication professionnelle. Les deux se disent sans problème, l'inversion est juste plus "polie".
2. Le présent est correct. Dans la mesure où tu peux tutoyer ton supérieur, il n'est pas nécessaire d'utiliser le conditionnel.
3. Une formulation active est à préférer dans le cadre de la communication en entreprise. Là encore, comme tu peux tutoyer ton supérieur, ce n'est pas un problème d'utiliser une tournure plus active.

En conclusion, je préfère la formulation : "Peux-tu me transmettre le document, s'il te plaît?"